# Is there risk of damaging my system or losing data while practicing is assembly language

Tags: assembly

I'm going to learn assembly, I have downloaded WinAsm IDE and MASM32. Assembly programing usually involves low level stuff , so before I start I wanted to ask if there is any risk of damaging my system or losing any data unintentionally while practicing is assembly.

Comment: Depends.  Please edit your question with more details of your system and how you intend to proceed.

Answer (score 2):

It depends whether you want to do assembly programming in kernel mode (implementing a driver) or user mode (implementing an application).

In kernel mode you can easily cause blue screens, which usually results in loss of unsaved data. In user mode, the application will crash and you'll only lose the data of this one application (your assembler application).

Answer (score 0):

Problems are hanging processes when your PC freezes and you have to reset it while some IO Operation is going on that can indeed damage your system. But newer OS like Win 7 and better are much better in killing hanging processes with the task manager.
Maybe you use a virtualbox (see at virtualbox.org) and do your assembly programming inside a virtual system. Also there are emulators like Bochs (http://bochs.sourceforge.net)